# How to change variables across different modules or js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am in the process of seperating my code so it is more clean. I have started doing this by putting my functions in their respective module. So instead of keeping it in the "index.js", I am keeping it in "change.js" (example name). Here is my function:

```
let number = 5;

function change(){
    number = number + 1;
}
```

The problem is, when I put this function in its own respective module called "change.js", when it is called, it gives the error that the variable "number" is not declared. If I then declare it in the "change.js" file, the variable "number" only changes in that file and not in "index.js". Is there anyway to change it in both files, or transfer the value from "change.js" to "index.js"?

Comment: Could you show how you are exporting and importing the values?

Answer (score 2):

Your change.js file should look something like this:

```
let number = 5;

const change = () => number = number + 1;

export { number, change }
```

And then, on your index.js you can import the variable as

```
import { number, change } from './change.js';
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I proceed to my answer this is how I exported and imported:

```
const change = require("./change");   //in index.js
```

```
module.exports {change); // in change.js
```

I found something that would make it work:

```
//in index.js & "number" and const "change" declared beforehand
number = change.change(number);
```

```
//in change.js
function change(number) {
    return number + 1;
}
//module.exports down here
```

This would then change the variable "number" in the index.js with the function "change" running from module "change.js"!

Comment: So exactly what @pmaroco proposed in their answer?

Comment: Don't think so... he suggested to export the variable while I returned it

Comment: Sorry, seems like I didn't look at your answer that closely. However, your question seems to indicate that you want to have a single number/variable that is shared across multiple modules and can be updated by multiple modules (that's how pmaroco answered it). But in your answer it looks like every module has its own number but uses the same function to operate on their own number. Please clarify in your question what you are really after. If you want to make a function *reusable* then yes, using parameterized function is the way to go about it.