# Change variable from different js

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

I am new to JS and am currently attempting to make some of my own projects. For one of them, I need to have the same variable in two scripts, I am using NodeJS. For example I want...

```
var text1
text1 = 'first text'
//in script1.js
```

to change variable `text1` to `'first text'` both in script1.js and script2.js and vice versa.
My first thought was to store `text1` in a txt document and read/write to it, but I think that this won't be so good. Any suggestions on how to do this without saving in a txt document would be appreciated. How to do it without saving in a txt, I'm looking for any solution that works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change variables across different modules or js files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66200912/how-to-change-variables-across-different-modules-or-js-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the keyword export before it

```
var text1
text1 = 'first text'
export text1
```

Then on the other file, you have to import it

```
import { text1 } from './script1.js'

console.log( text1 )
```

---

You can export multiple items and make a function to change that variable.

```
var text1 = 'first text';

const change = (value) => text1 = value;

export { text1 , change }
```

and then

```
import { text1 , change } from './script1.js';

console.log( text1 )

change('hello world!')

console.log( text1 )
```

---

If you want to export a single variable from a single file you can also make it a default export by adding the default keyword after the export keyword

```
var text1
text1 = 'first text'
export default text1
```

Then you don't need to put the curly braces { } in the import statement

```
import text1 from './script1.js'

console.log( text1 )
```

Hope you get your answer.

Comment: Export part works fine I used ```export {text1}``` instead of ```export text1```, but when I want to import it like so ```import {text1} from './script1.js'; console.log(text1);``` Im getting an error:   ```import {text1} from './script1.js';
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module``` Im importing it in the first line of the code. I also tried ```var {text1} = require('./script1.js'); console.log(text1)```, then Im getting error: ```export { text1 } SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'```

Comment: @RuKu are you doing that in a script tag?

Comment: no plain .js file, and running it with cmd

Comment: add `"type": "module",` in the `package.json` file

Comment: I dont have package.json, its just one single .js file

Comment: then run `npm init -y` and create the `package.json` file.

Comment: I dont want to install whole init, I want it to be a singe .js or .mjs file

Comment: in that case you can run `node --experimental-modules script2.mjs `